Blender 4.2 Switching Geometry
In Blender v4.2, I am trying to hide parts of an object generated by geometry nodes, where it intersects with another object.
The documentation says that the Result output of the Compare (Greater Than) node is boolean, but the Switch node won*t accept it as a valid input.


I think you want to use a Delete Geometry node set to Instance mode instead of the switch node, the diamond shaped node socket implies that the result is indeed a boolean, but a boolean field, not a boolean scalar (single value). The round shaped input socket of the switch node implies it expects a single boolean value.
